# Tomcat ssl configuration

Tags: ssl, tomcat

I recently downloaded a certificate from startssl and I'm trying to enable ssl on my tomcat 7.0.6 (I didn't generate de req file). I configured and when I tried to start it, the following error showed up:

```
java.io.IOException: Alias name ssltest does not identify a key entry
```

When I list the certificates in my keystore, I find that "ssltest" has "Entry type: trustedCertEntry" whereas "tomcat" has "Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry". What step am I missing ? (I already imported ca.pem and sub.class1.server.ca.pem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the key into the keystore using a custom import.  The native import functionality of `keytool` does not import the key properly.  I have used WebLogic to import the key.  I haven't need to find a tool for Tomcat.